# Non WWW to WWW redirection using htaccess File

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am using Codeigniter-.
My domain currently does not redirect to `www` version.

For example if I type `mydomain.com` then it stays `mydomain.com`. I want to redirect it to `www.mydomain.com`.

If someone types `mydomain.com/controller/method` then it should be `www.mydomain.com/controller/method`.

Another problem: I already tried other solutions but the problem is when it redirects to `www` version, it automatically adds  "`index.php`" in the URL. But when I type `www` in the domain name then it works fine, no "`index.php`" in the URL. This problem occurs only during the redirection.

Here is my `.htaccess` file (I've removed the redirection code)

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|system|rpc_relay.html|canvas.html|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond $1 !^(sitemap\.xml|export)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide the full `.htaccess` file so you'll get a full `.htaccess` file answer you'll just have to copy/paste **`;)`**

Answer (score 2):

To redirect from `http://` to `http://www`. , and also remove the route file (`index.php`) in the url, put these lines on your htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|styles|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

the domain is :

```
domain.com
```

folder with direct access :

```
images|css|js|styles
```

hope this help

Comment: hi.. i am getting some problem when i am using this.. i am redirecting on main domain when i am putting subdomain URL instead of www. for eg: when i am using http://m.domain.com than it is redirecting on main http://www.domain.com. why is this happening? do you have any idea? please help me.

Comment: @SandeepTawaniya, correct me if I'm wrong, but as I interpret the above code it will only be able to do add the www if the domain is visited without it. That said, other subdomains will not work with the above .htaccess rules.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the following before:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.+)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks but having the same problem When I type "mydomain.com" it takes me to "www.mydomain.com/index.php". I actually want to get rid off "index.php". In my config file we already set this to $config['index_page'] = "";

Answer (score 0):

To redirect `domain.com` to `www.domain.com`, you could use the following rewrite rule. Please replace `domain.com` with your own domain name.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Redirection perfectly works but the issue is that it adds "index.php" in the domain. When I type "mydomain.com" it takes me to "www.mydomain.com/index.php". I actually want to get rid off "index.php". In my config file we already set this to $config['index_page'] = "";

Comment: Now working fine. I actually put this in the wrong line that why "index.php" was appearing again. Thanks!!

Comment: @Tuhin Please mention how you solved the issue. It would be helpful for a lot of people.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why there are such complex RewriteRules answers, even though Gobhi has provided a nice generic solution (= whatever the domain name is, it works).
Here's my solution.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

  RewriteRule (.*)/index\.php$ $1/ [QSA]
</IfModule>
```